# Why my canary deployment does not work with istio?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio

I am trying to learn the basics about istio so I have gone through the official documentation [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/) in order to create a 80/20 canary deployment, I have also follow this guide from digitalocean which explains it very easy for a simple deployment https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-do-canary-deployments-with-istio-and-kubernetes.

I have created a simple app with 2 different messages on the homepage, and then created the virtualService, Gateway and the destination rules. I (as mentioned in the guide) get the external ip with `kubectl -n istio-system  get svc` and the try to navigate to that address but I get a 503 error. It seems very simple but I have to be missing something. These are my 3 files (as far as I understand there are no more necessary files):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  namespace: istio
  name: flask-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - "*"
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: flask-app
  namespace: istio
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - flask-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: flask-app
        subset: v1
      weight: 80
    - destination:
        host: flask-app
        subset: v2
      weight: 20
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: flask-app
  namespace: istio
spec:
  host: flask-app
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

Here are the yaml with deployment and services for v1 and v2:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    version: v1
  name: flask-deployment-v1
  namespace: istio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        version: v1
        app: flask-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-app
        image: latalavera/flask-app:1.3
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-service
  namespace: istio
spec:
  selector:
    app: flask-app
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    version: v2
  name: flask-deployment-v2
  namespace: istio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask-app
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-app
        image: latalavera/flask-app:2.0
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-service2
  namespace: istio
spec:
  selector:
    app: flask-app
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  type: ClusterIP
```

I have added the labels `version: v1` and `version: v2` to my deployments, and I have also used the `kubectl label ns istio istio-injection=enabled`  command, but they are not working anyways

Comment: Is your ``flask-app`` deployed in the ``istio-system`` namespace?

Comment: it is deployed in the istio namespace which I created, I thought the ```kubectl label ns istio istio-injection=enabled``` made the resources available in other namespaces

Comment: I just tried deploying everything in ns istio-system and I keep getting a 503...according to the guid I just need to copy paste the external ip from the  istio-ingressgateway, which I get through ```kubectl -n istio-system get svc``` command right

Comment: No sorry, the question was if it is deployed there. I should not be running in the istio-system ns. Can you add the manifest for deployment and service please

Comment: @ChristophRaab I have updated it with that. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You named the service `flask-service` and set the `host` in your `VirtualService` to `flask-app`.

The `host` field is not a selector but the `FQDN` of the service you want to route the traffic to. So it should be called `flask-service` or better `flask-service.istio.svc.cluster.local`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: flask-app
  namespace: istio
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - flask-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: flask-service.istio.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
      weight: 80
    - destination:
        host: flask-service.istio.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v2
      weight: 20
```

Alternatively you could just call the service `flask-app` like the `Deployment`. But using the full `FQDN` `<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local` is recommended in any case. From docs:

> Note for Kubernetes users: When short names are used (e.g. “reviews” instead of “reviews.default.svc.cluster.local”), Istio will interpret the short name based on the namespace of the rule, not the service. A rule in the “default” namespace containing a host “reviews” will be interpreted as “reviews.default.svc.cluster.local”, irrespective of the actual namespace associated with the reviews service. To avoid potential misconfigurations, it is recommended to always use fully qualified domain names over short names.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService -> hosts

You btw don't need 2 services, just one. Your service has a `selector` for `app: flask-app` so it can route traffic to v1 and v2. How the traffic is routed is defined by the `VirtualService` and `DestionationRule`. I would recommand to remove service `flask-service2`. If you need to route the traffic inside the mesh, add `mesh` as `gateways` in the `VirtualService` or create a new one for mesh internal traffic, to reach both versions. More on that topic:

https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService -> gateways

Comment: thanks a lot for the exaplanation I have changed as you mention but I still get a 503 error. I just need to copy paste the external ip address from the ```service/istio-ingressgateway ``` and it should work right? that is how it is done in the digitalocean guide

Comment: doing a ping to the istio-ingressgateway works, but I get a 503 when trying to acces in the browser

Comment: are you running on digital ocean or some other cloud provider or on premise or something like minikube? Have you tried to access the workload without istio? Deploy it in a different namespace and set the service's type to LoadBalancer. The service gets an external ip, that can be used. If that works I would recommand setting up prometheus/kiali to investigate further. There must be something slighly wrong, because the setup seems to be correct now.

Comment: I am using a cluster in GCP, I have used the app with helm charts and also with k8s (without istio) with a nginx ingress-controller and both works fine. Unfortunately as I said I am learning about k8s and istio (I have been praciticing for 2-3 weeks) and I have no idea how to use prometheus or kiali

Comment: Run ``kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.8/samples/addons/prometheus.yaml`` and ``helm install --namespace istio-system --set auth.strategy="anonymous" --repo https://kiali.org/helm-charts kiali-server kiali-server`` to install a basic setup and after successful setup you can proxy into kilai by ``istioctl dashboard kiali`` and open presented the link in the browser. Check all sections for warnings and errors.

Comment: I get this error when applying the first command: ```The Deployment "prometheus" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"prometheus", "component":"server", "release":"prometheus"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable```

Comment: and this error when applying the second command ```Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ConfigMap "kiali" in namespace "istio-system" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "kiali-server"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "istio-system```

Comment: Which istio version and which profile of istio do you have installed? Try the ``istioctl dashboard kiali`` command. Does it work? Maybe it's already installed